# Make appharbor work with existing mysql server

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc-3, appharbor

When I was working on my project (asp.net mvc 3) before uploading it, I needed to make it refer to an already existing mysql database. There was/is no option of moving or cloning that database, and I had to add a block of code to my C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config file for it to be made compatible.

How do I make it work on appharbor without moving my database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use `mysqldump` to move your data to a database running in the context of the [AppHarbor MySQL add-on](https://appharbor.com/addons/mysql). [Here's a guide](http://julianschrader.de/20090221-mysql-moving-databases-easily-with-mysqldump/).

If your current database is publicly accessible it should also work if you configure your AppHarbor app to use that. If you need to open a firewall, you can find AppHarbor app server IPs [here](http://support.appharbor.com/kb/tips-and-tricks/application-server-ips-ec2-configuration).